# Adding Properties boxes on the spot inside a form tag

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

i have the following elements:
[image: Html format]

In react I just declared the following:

```
  const [type, setType] = useState("");
  const [propertyName, setPropertyName] = useState("");
```

The html is the following:

```
           <div>
            <label htmlFor='properties' className='properties-label'>
              Properties
            </label>
            <div className='property-box'>
              <input
                type='text'
                id='type'
                placeholder='Type'
                className='type-element'
                required
                onChange={(e) => setType(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <input
                type='text'
                id='name'
                className='type-element'
                placeholder='Name'
                required
                onChange={(e) => setPropertyName(e.target.value)}
              ></input>
              <button className='buttonAccount' type='submit'>
                Add Property
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
```

What I want to basically is somehow to add a property, containing the two values. I was thinking using an array to store some objects like the following example:
{
type: card
name: Dragon
}

But I don't really know how to tackle this problem. Should I first create an empty array and then store those two fields in an object? How is this done? How can I make sure that both of the fields are completed(they shouldn't go to the database if one of them is empty). After these two fields are inputted I want a new element appear right underneath those fields, like a paragraph with the data that I introduced, an example that I saw is familiar with this is on OpenSea, when creating an NFT(https://opensea.io/asset/create)
Can somebody explain me a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have a look on this code

```
https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-lake-059b82?file=/src/App.js:0-1339
```

to make paragraph visible create one more state and update it on handleClick function

Comment: That's a pretty good example, thanks so much. For the paragraph tag I will try and add it a return tag using ` `.